# Batching & CAT Command

Tags: unix, cat

I'm trying to add a string to the beginning of many files, creating a new file extension whilst maintaining the filename.

```
cat string.txt file001.old > file001.new
cat string.txt file002.old > file002.new
cat string.txt file003.old > file003.new
etc...
```

I tried to batch it by:

```
for i in *.old
do
    cat string.txt $i > $i.new
done
```

But this didnt exactly work, my skills are limited...
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is not working? Is `string.txt` a file (if not, you need to `echo` the string). Or do you have new files with names like `file002.old.new` ? Or do you have filenames with spaces that get mixed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or this shorter alternative

```
for i in *.old
do
  echo string.txt | cat - $i > ${i%old}new
done
```

or even with heredoc instead of pipe

```
for i in *.old
do
  cat - $i <<< string.txt > ${i%old}new
done
```

Comment: I used the 1st method but I had to use puncutation marks again for it to work without errors; echo string.txt | cat - "$i" > "${i%old}new"

Comment: True, but I didn't add the quotes as they were not in the original example

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. This may be the simplest:

```
for i in *.old
do
  echo string.txt > ${i%old}new
  cat $i >> ${i%old}new
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys... I forgot to add the punctuation marks, Should look something like this:

```
for i in *.old
do
    cat string.txt "$i" > "$i".new
done
```

The output would look like "file002.old.new"
Where I used SED to remove the old extention
But I will definitely be trying the alternate methods

Thanks again, Nem